# GROUP_CONCAT on two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have those tables:

**Party**

```
id | date | place
```

**Party_Attendands**

```
id | party_id | person_id | unknow_person_id
```

**Persons**

```
id | name | lastname
```

I want to denormalize some data and avoid the use of Party_Attendands.
Basically I want a view like

**Party & PartyPeople**

```
id | date       | place | attendands_list
0  | 01/01/2016 | NY    | 1,2,3,4
```

The query below returns the `person_ids`, but not the `unknow_person_ids`. People who crashed the party are person too :).
If it's not clear, `unknow_person_ids` are just ids which are **not** present in `Persons`. So each row of `Party_Attendands` contains a `person_id` or `unknow_person_id` but **not** both.

So `attendands_list` should contains `person_ids` and `unknow_person_ids`, currently handles just the former.

```
SELECT party.party_id, party.date, attendands.list
FROM party
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT party_id , GROUP_CONCAT( Party_Attendands.person_id
  ORDER BY person_id
  SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS list
  FROM Party_Attendands
  GROUP BY Party_Attendands.party_id 
) AS attendands 
ON party.party_id  = attendands.party_id
```

Comment: There is no question...

Comment: Are your `person_id` values and your `unknown_person_id` values taken from the same sequence of numbers? Can a Person have the same id value as a different Unknown person?

Comment: No, there is no way to have ambiguous data. (`unknown_person_id`  starts from 1000, `person_id` ends about 300 )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: There is no question if you don't read the entire post. I would like to know the reason of the downvotes.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect people downvoted because many question posts start with the question and then give the background. They way you structured your question is called *burying the lede* in English-language journalism: we have to study the post to find the key point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR  Use `UNION`.

You can take the union of person_id and unknown_person_id values, like so.

```
                SELECT party_id, person_id
                  FROM Party_Attendands
                 UNION          
                SELECT party_id, unknown_person_id AS person_id
                  FROM Party_Attendands
```

Then you can group these items, like so:

```
   SELECT party_id, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT person_id ORDER BY person_id) persons
     FROM (
                SELECT party_id, person_id
                  FROM Party_Attendands
                 UNION          
                SELECT party_id, unknown_person_id AS person_id
                  FROM Party_Attendands
          ) a
    GROUP BY party_id
```

Then you can join that result to your other table.

```
SELECT p.id party_id, p.date, p.place, q.persons
  FROM Party p
  LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT party_id, 
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT person_id ORDER BY person_id) persons
             FROM (
                        SELECT party_id, person_id
                          FROM Party_Attendands
                         UNION          
                        SELECT party_id, unknown_person_id
                          FROM Party_Attendands
                  ) a
            GROUP BY party_id
       ) q ON p.id = q.party_id
```

I suppose it's not a party if nobody shows up. But still, `LEFT JOIN` will allow your result set to show rows from your `Party` table even if no corresponding rows appear in your other table.

Comment: Some are failed party :) so I used `left outer join`. I tried yours and I'm not sure why it still handles the failed party with a plain `left join`. Anyway I made it works with 2 rough `left outer join`, yours is better and I will use it.